# C# Visual Studio Open New Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, window

I am new to C# and Visual Studio,
But I started a little project that opens a main window and shows a table.
The Presenter of the window contains an Observable:

```
public ObservableCollection<FruitsPresenter> Fruits { get; set; }
```

This collections contains information about some fruits.
Then It shows a table of all i'ts content.
I made a button that supposed to open a new window and create a 'entry form'
that will ask for information and then add to the collection a new item.

I couldn't manage to do it. Any help?

Comment: What couldn't you manage to do? What did you try? What happened?

Comment: Well, I managed to add it, But when I try to add another one in the addFruit window, it keeps editing the last added fruit.

Comment: We need to see the code that "add another one".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a new form and opening it is very simple in C#/Visual Studio.

Do the following:

1. **Add a new *form* to your project:**

   Do this by right-clicking your project and choose: Add -> Windows Form.
2. **Name the form**
3. **Create new instance of form and call form:**

Go to the location where the new form should be called from. Add following code there:

```
NewForm newFrm = new NewForm();
newFrm.Show();
```

New form will be visible when application calls code above.

Comment: I ment Using this on the XAML side. I will not be using directly C# for UI